# Jquery combining many option select in to one input on multiple lines and combinding a total sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i made a little code that combine from multiple options select and a textarea to one input.
But i want the code to run on 10 different lines exactly the same, but instead of having the jquery 10 times how do i it so i can use the same code to run of 10 different lines?

Second of all so if one option select is selected medium lets say 3 colors.
And another line i get medium 1 color. So the total would be 4 medium how do i combine all those to one input?

And problem number 3, im trying to calculate if i got 4 medium and the next input to that total is price for medium how do i total medium*price=total? So like in the example 4 * 5 = 20 would be the output!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    sum();
    $("#totalsmall, #smallprice").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        sum();
    });
    $("#totalmedium, #mediumprice").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        sum();
    });
    $("#totallarge, #largeprice").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        sum();
    });
});

function sum() {
    var totalsmall = document.getElementById('totalsmall').value;
    var smallprice = document.getElementById('smallprice').value;
 var result = parseInt(smallprice) * parseInt(totalsmall);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('totalsmallprice').value = result;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combine').on('change', function(){
        var alltext = 'Location : ' + $('#location').val() + ', Print Size : ' + $('#size').val() + ', Print Colors : ' + $('#colors').val() + ', Description : ' + $('#description').val();
        $('#fillinput').val(alltext);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SELECT class="combine" id="location">
    <option>Print Location</option>
    <option>Front Body</option>
    <option>Back Body</option>
    <option>Left Arm</option>
    <option>Right Arm</option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT class="combine" id="size">
    <option>Printing Size</option>
    <option>Small</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Large</option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT class="combine" id="colors">
    <option>Print Colors</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</SELECT>
<textarea class="combine" id="description"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="fillinput" value="">
<br>


<SELECT class="combine1" id="location">
    <option>Print Location</option>
    <option>Front Body</option>
    <option>Back Body</option>
    <option>Left Arm</option>
    <option>Right Arm</option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT class="combine1" id="size">
    <option>Printing Size</option>
    <option>Small</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Large</option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT class="combine1" id="colors">
    <option>Print Colors</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</SELECT>
<textarea class="combine1" id="description"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="fillinput" value="">

<br>

<SELECT class="combine2" id="location">
    <option>Print Location</option>
    <option>Front Body</option>
    <option>Back Body</option>
    <option>Left Arm</option>
    <option>Right Arm</option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT class="combine2" id="size">
    <option>Printing Size</option>
    <option>Small</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Large</option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT class="combine2" id="colors">
    <option>Print Colors</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</SELECT>
<textarea class="combine2" id="description"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="fillinput" value="">

<br>
<br>

Total Small : <input type="number" id="totalsmall" value="" placeholder="Total Small">
Price : <input type="number" id="smallprice" value="2">
Total Price : <input type="number" id="totalsmallprice" value="" readonly>
<br>
Total Medium : <input type="number" id="totalmedium" value="" placeholder="Total Medium">
Price : <input type="number" id="mediumprice" value="5">
Total Price : <input type="number" id="totalmediumprice" value="" readonly>
<br>
Total Large : <input type="number" id="totallarge" value="" placeholder="Total Large">
Price : <input type="number" id="largeprice" value="7">
Total Price : <input type="number" id="totallargeprice" value="" readonly>
<br>
```

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please note that you should not have multiple elements with the same id `colors, size`

Comment: Yeah i get that.. i guess it will be something like location1 location2 and so on!

Comment: Just use common class $(".combine").on("keydown keyup", function() { sum(); });